# What are the tickets for?

Tags: cook-serve-delicious

Occasionally I get an email with gold or silver tickets attached. The game shows me in the top right how many of each kind I've collected. I must have missed when the game explained what they are useful for, however.

What can I do with all these tickets I'm getting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The silver tickets can be used to make bets. Somewhere around day 10, your email client gains the bet button, which allows you to wager silver tokens to attempt to reach a certain combo with a randomly determined active menu.

[image: Screenshot of betting interface]

Golden tickets become useful once you reach a 4-star rating. Spoiler below:

> Once you reach that rating, you'll be contacted by the secret clan of the Temple of Delicious. This will unlock the Hungry Festivities as the third Extra Event. Golden tickets are used to unlock challenges in the Hungry Festivities. [image: Screenshot of third Extra Event] [image: Screenshot of third Extra Event]